# Branch of the n-th root of a holomorphic function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, radicals

It is true that given a domain $D$ and a function $f$ that is holomorphic and not vanishing in $D$, then a branch $\varphi$ (with $\varphi$ continuous) of $f^{1/n}$ in $D$ is holomorphic in $D$ ([here is a proof for that statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948741/holomorphic-branch-of-the-n-mathrmth-root-of-f) ).

My question is, does the statement remain true if we remove the non-vanishing condition? I haven't been able to find a counterexample or a proof on that more general case.

Comment: Are you *assuming* that $\varphi$ is continuous (as in the referenced question)?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that... Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The formulation of your question confused me. Perhaps you should ask: If $\varphi$ is a continuous $n$-th root of $f$, is $\varphi$ homolomorphic?

Comment: You mean $D$ is simply connected. Removing the zeros you get a non-simply connected $U$. You may look at the monodromy of $f^{1/2}$ say $ f(z)=(z+1)(z-1)$ : for each closed curve $\gamma$ find how $f^{1/2}$ transforms (to $\pm f^{1/2}$) when continuing it analytically along $\gamma$. This monodromy group is a quotient of the fundamental group of $U$ and $f^{1/2}$ is holomorphic iff its monodromy is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is holomorphic in $D$ and $\varphi$  continuous in $D$ with $\varphi^n = f$ then $\varphi$ is also holomorphic in $D$. Under these conditions it is not necessary to assume that $f$ does not vanish in $D$.

First consider $\varphi$ restricted to $D' =  \{ z \in D : f(z) \ne 0 \}$: $\varphi|_{D'}$ is holomorphic because it is locally equal to $\exp(\frac 1n \log z)$ for some branch of the logarithm. Or more elementary: If $f(z_0) \ne 0$ then for $z$ close to $z_0$:
$$
 \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0)} = \frac{\varphi(z)^n-\varphi(z_0)^n}{z-z_0}
 \\
= \frac{\varphi(z)-\varphi(z_0)}{z-z_0} \cdot \left(
\varphi(z)^{n-1} + \varphi(z)^{n-2}\varphi(z_0) + \ldots \varphi(z)\varphi(z_0)^{n-2} + \varphi(z_0)^{n-1}
\right)
$$
And since the term in parentheses on the right has the non-zero limit
$(n-1) \varphi(z_0)^{n-1} $ for $z\to z_0$ it follows that the limit
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{\varphi(z)-\varphi(z_0)}{z-z_0}
= \frac{1}{(n-1) \varphi(z_0)^{n-1}} f'(z_0)
$$
exists, i.e. $\varphi $ is differentiable at $z_0$.

It remains to consider the points in $D$ with $f(z_0)=0$. At all these points, $\varphi|_{D'}$ has an isolated singularly, and that is *removable* because $\lim_{z\to z_0} \varphi(z) = 0$, according to [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem).

It follows that $\varphi|_{D'}$ can be holomorphically extended to $D$, and that extension does of course coincide with $\varphi$ (since both functions are continuous).

This proves that $\varphi$ is in holomorphic in $D$.

Comment: Perhaps it is a bit nitpicky, but I wouldn't say that $\varphi$ has singularities at the points $z_0 \in f^{-1}(0)$ because $\varphi$ is defined in these points. I would prefer to say that the holomorphic function $\varphi \mid_{D \setminus f^{-1}(0)}$ has singularities at these points which are removable.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Thanks for the feedback – better now?

Comment: As I said, perhaps a bit nitpicky, but I think it's better. btw typo:  homomorphically extended

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. Take $f(z)=z$ and $n=2$, for instance. There is no holomorphic functions (or even a continuous one) from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$ such that $\varphi^2=f$. If there was, and if $k$ was the order of $0$ as a zero of $\varphi$, then $0$ would be a zero of otder $2k$ of $f$. But $0$ is a zero of order $1$ of $f$.

Comment: I was assuming that $\varphi$  was continuous as in the link I referenced. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did I answer your question or not?

Comment: I meant that $\varphi$ continuous is assumed by hypothesis, but I forgot to add that in the original post.

Comment: All right. But did I answer your question or not?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The question was unclear, but after clarification it seems that your answer does not adress the question. In fact, $f(z) = z$ does not have a continuous square root, but the OP wants to know what can be said about a continuous $n$-th root (if such a function exists).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So perhaps a better question would be this: Is it possible that a  holomorphic function with isolated zeros has a holomorphic $n$-th root? You gave a counterexample, but I think if the zeros have degree $mn$, then it could be possible.

Comment: @PaulFrost Of course: $z^2$ has two holomprphic square roots: $\pm z$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The "adequate" question would then be. Under what conditions does a  holomorphic function with isolated zeros have a continuous $n$-th root?

Comment: If it has only finitely many zeros, the condition is: the order of each zero is even. Otherwise, I do not know the answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it doesn't matter if the number of zeros is finite as long as we are on a simple connected domain $D$; assuming $f$ not constant, number them $(z_k,2n_k), z_k \ne z_m$ for $k \ne m, 2n_k \ge 2$ the order of the respective zero; construct a holomorphic $h$ on $D$ with zeros precisely $(z_k,n_k)$ and then $\frac{f}{h^2}$ is non-zero, hence has a square root $g$, so $gh$ is a square root of $f$; if the domain is not simply connected, non-zero functions may not have continuos square roots and you need algebraic topology to give precise conditions in term of cycles, divisors etc

Comment: @Conrad That's nice!