# On differentiability of continuous square root

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.  Can we find a continuous function $f:U\longrightarrow{\mathbb{C}}$ such that $(f(z))^2 = z$ for all $z\in{U}$, and such that it isn't differentiable at some $z_0$ in $U$?

I think it's not possible, but I am not sure.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3243819/42969.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that for all $z\in U$, $f(z)\ne0$ and therefore, by continuity of $f$, $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(f(z+h))^2-(f(z))^2}{h(f(z+h)+f(z))}=\frac1{2f(z)}$$