# Finding derivative of $f(z) =\sqrt r[\cos\theta/2 +i \sin\theta/2]$, where $r>0$ and $0<\theta<2π$.

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Show that $f(z) =\sqrt r [\cos\theta/2 +i \sin\theta/2]$, where $r>0$, $0<\theta<2π$ is differentiable. Find $f'(z)$.

I have tried to solve it by cauchy-rieman(CR equation) but got stuck in midway. Please help me to solve it. Thanks a lot

Comment: *Hint:* What is $f(z)^2$ ? – Then use https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3721705/42969.

Comment: Thanks sir, trying by your suggestion

Comment: Is $\alpha$ the argument of $z$? It's usually denoted $\theta\in(-\pi,\,\pi]$, so maybe $\alpha=\theta+\pi$. This is important in determining whether $f^2$ is $z$ or $-z$, or whatever.

Comment: @J.G sir question is same as posted here. Here no $\theta$ exists

Comment: @Rajakr Never mind $\theta$: what is $z$ in terms of $r,\,\alpha$?