# Show that $g(re^{i\theta}) = \sqrt[n]{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{n}}$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, be defined for every $r \in (0, \infty)$, and $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$ as $g(re^{i\theta}) = \sqrt[n]{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{n}}$.

I have to show that g is well defined and holomorphic without using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. I know that, as $U$ is simply connected, if the 1-Form $w = \frac {g(z)}{z^2+1}$ is holomorphic then it is also local exact (Goursat´s theorem), but I do not really know if this theorem works for this case, as the implication goes to the other direction that I want.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should define $U.$

Comment: The generalization of this statement: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948741/holomorphic-branch-of-the-n-mathrmth-root-of-f and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243819/branch-of-the-n-th-root-of-a-holomorphic-function-is-holomorphic

Comment: I concur with @Winther that this question is answered by [Branch of the n-th root of a holomorphic function is holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243819/branch-of-the-n-th-root-of-a-holomorphic-function-is-holomorphic). Therefore I am voting to close this question as a duplicate. Others may disagree, and it usually takes five votes to finish closing a question, but that’s my opinion.